# Oracle Toad "Editor" tab missing

Tags: toad

I'm using oracle toad version 9. 
Accidentally I have removed Editor tab in Toad.
Can I display Editor tab again in bottom

[Original view of Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac11m.jpg)

[Present situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAi7N.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the Window Bar. Right click over the main Toad toolbar and make sure that Window Bar is checked. If it is and you don't see it docked to any side of Toad then right click over the main Toad toolbar and choose "Restore defaults."